# Story identification - huge abandoned spaceship

Tags: story-identification

Trying to remember title (and even most content!) of following story:

Something along the lines of a gigantic abandoned spaceship drifting through the galaxy for over a galactic turn, humans had colonised it and run it, and trade passage on the spaceship with other races in return for technology/goods. Think the main plot was over an attempted take over of the ship by another race.

Apologies for vagueness.

Comment: Hi - is there any other information you can provide?  For example, when you read it, the approximate age of the book, U.S., British, other..?  Was it a book?  Story in a magazine?  Do you recall any artwork?

Comment: This is so vague, it could even be _Rama_.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's probably the Great Ship series by Robert Reed, of which the first entry is the novel *[Marrow](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marrow_(novel))*.

> When a jovian sized, artificially-created structure enters the galaxy,
>   a society of technologically advanced humans (capable of interstellar
>   flight and functionally immortal) are the first to intercept and
>   investigate it. Finding it to be an intergalactic ship, they decide to
>   convert it into a cruise ship, inviting alien races to join them in
>   its massive, uncharted interior as it makes a slow circumnavigation of
>   the Milky Way.

Comment: Woops, looks like you beat me by a few seconds.  I'll delete mine but just point out that, if it is indeed this book, it's also the answer to http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1030/65768

Comment: It was the Marrow book - thanks for much for the reminder!